# how I can use join in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following tables:

**User**

```
id | name | nick
```

**Relationship**

```
idUser1 | idUser2 | status
```

How can I find out the friend's name (where `status` = `"friend"` on the relationship table), for a user with id 1 (joining on `relationship.idUser1`)

I tried this but it's no working

```
dcChatDataContext db = new dcChatDataContext();
var name = from u in db.user
join r in db.relationship on u.id equals r.idUser2
where r.idUser1 == 1
select new { completename = u.name+ ' ' + u.nick };
```

Comment: [101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: Your code, at a second glance, will actually work perfectly. Could you explain further why it's not what you're expecting? It currently will return the names of all the friends of user `1`

Answer (score 2):

In your above snippet

```
 where r.idUser1== 1
```

condition is wrong use `where u.id==1` instead of that.

Full snippet is as below:

```
dcChatDataContext db = new dcChatDataContext();
var name = (from u in db.user
join r in db.relationship on u.id equals r.idUser1
where u.id== 1 && r.status=="friend"
select new { completename = u.name+ ' ' + u.nick }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This really is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Brendan: How is it not an answer? Because you felt it was too short? Even before his edit, the answer was fine.

Comment: Note sure why this is upvoted. It filters on `u.id` and then returns the properties on `u` after joining. This will return the information for user `1` multiple times (one row for each relationship). It will not return the information of the friend.

Comment: Yes,I have corrected my mistake.Thanks for given right direction. @Rob

Comment: @DharmeshParmar This still does not return the friends. It will just return the user with id `1` if they have a friend. The original code OP posted was correct, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Rob Is this "u.id equals r.idUser2" right in OP's post? I am asking because he has mentioned (joining on relationship.idUser1).